# Python Datetime 先月を取得したいです。

Tags: python

Pythonを使って日付を使って先月を欲しいです。
こちらの場合だと、うまくいかない月もあります。

```
import datetime
sengetu = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-30)
sengetu = sengetu.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(sengetu)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/somen/PycharmProjects/2/s.py", line 2, in 
>       sengetu = datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-30) NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-30日だと、うまくいかない月もありますので、`dateutil`モジュールの使用をおすすめします。

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = date.today()
sengetu = today - relativedelta(months=1)

print(sengetu)
```

`dateutil`モジュールは`pip`でインストールできます。

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

※Python3の場合

Answer (score 2):

```
timedelta(days=-30)
```

このコードを

```
datetime.timedelta(days=-30)
```

に修正してください。